# Does this Graph converge in a finite number of steps? How fast is it?

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you have a finite, planar Graph $G = (V,E)$ and a function $f_0:V \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$.

Now you define the function $f_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$  like this:

$$f_i(v) := \frac{f_{i-1}(v) + \sum_{(v,w) \in E} f_{i-1}(w)}{1 + \text{number of vertices that are  adjacent to } v}$$

In words: In each step, you go through each vertex and build the average of all vertices that are adjacent and the vertex itself and you assign this value to the vertex.

## Examples

### Example 1

You have two vertices that are connected:

Step 0: 14 - 42
Step 1: 28 - 28

Ready, it converged in a finite number of steps

### Example 2

You have 10 vertices that are always only connected to the vertex before:

- Step 0: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
- Step 1: [1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 9.5]
- Step 2: [1.75, 2.1666666666666665, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 8.833333333333334, 9.25]
- Step 3: [1.9583333333333333, 2.3055555555555554, 3.0555555555555554, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 7.9444444444444455, 8.694444444444445, 9.041666666666668]
- Step 4: [2.131944444444444, 2.4398148148148144, 3.1203703703703702, 4.018518518518518, 5.0, 6.0, 6.981481481481482, 7.879629629629631, 8.560185185185185, 8.868055555555557]

(I let this run with [a python script](https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/5178175). According to this, it converges after 861 steps. But I guess it only converges because of finite precision)

### Example 3

I wanted to show you a triangle, but I've just realized that any complete graph will converge in only one step.

### Example 4

[image]

The numbers get really ugly now. I am not even sure if this one converges at all. Before I wrote this example, I thought that all vertices  would converge to 
$$\frac{\sum_{v \in V} f_0(v)}{|V|}$$, but now I'm not even sure if this is correct.

### Example 5

[image]

Now I am sure that the value of the vertices doesn't always converge to the average as the sum of all vertices should not change in that case.

## Question

If you have any Graph like I described above, can you determine an upper bound as a function of $n = |V|$ how fast the Graph will converge? Does it always converge? If not, can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of your graph and let $D$ be the diagonal matrix of the same order with $D_{i,i}$ equal to 1 plus the degree of the $i$-vertex.
Then your update rule is to replace $f$ by $D^{-1}(I+A)f$.

Note that $D^{-1}(I+A)$ is row stochastic and nonnegative and so describes a Markov chain on the vertices of the graph. If your graph is connected and all
entries of $f$ are non-negative, it follows that $(D^{-1}(I+A))^nf)$ will converge to a limit, which will be an eigenvector for $D^{-1}(I+A)$, associated to the largest eigenvalue.

These are all standard facts, and will be treated in many introductory books on Markov chains. (They are also consequences of the Perron-Frobenius theory,
in linear algebra.)

Edit: I'm using convergence above in the usual sense, but now I see this is not what you asked for. My mistake, but consider the following.

Set $M=D^{-1}(A+I)$ and let $x$ be the all-ones vector. Then $Mx=x$.
Assume $M^{k+1}f=M^kf$. Then $M^kf$ is an eigenvector for $M$ with eigenvalue 1.
From the theory referred to above, it follows that $M^kf=cx$ for some $c$.
Hence $M^k(f-cx)=0$.

Suppose $E$ is the non-negative diagonal matrix such that $E^2=D$. Then
$$
  M = D^{-1}(A+I) = E^{-1} (E^{-1}(A+I)E^{-1}) E.
$$
Thus $M$ is similar to a symmetric matrix, therefore it is diagonalizable,
and therefore if $M^k(f-cx)=0$, then $M(f-cx)=0$. 
(So $Mf=cMx =cx$ and $M^2f=cMx=cx=Mf$. Hence $M^2f=Mf$ and we have shown that if
$M^{k+1}f=M^kf$, then $k=1$.)

If $M(f-cx)=0$, then $D^{-1}(A+I)(f-cx)=0$. So choose a vector $y$ such that
its entries sum to zero and $(A+I)y=0$. Then $D^{-1}(A+I)(ax+y) = ax$ (for any $a$)
and $M^2(ax+y)=M(ax+y)$.

As an example, take the path on five vertices with $y=(1,-1,0,1,-1)$ and $a=1$, 
giving $f=(2,0,1,2,0)$.

Comment: Could you please go through example 4? And thanks for mentioning Markov chains. We have a lecture where they teach Markov chains and I now think I'll take it. It sounds interesting now :-)

Comment: Here is my try: http://pastebin.com/T5SCVxPT